# CentOS7 home server doesn't automatically start services

Tags: linux, ssh, centos-7

I'm new to CentOS. I recently bought a CentOS machine but it doesn't automatically start some services on boot. I want `sshd.service` be automatically started at boot, what should I do?

I tried `chkconfig sshd` on but nothing happened, the same as adding `systemctl enable sshd.service` on the bottom of `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` file.

Machine : CentOS7.2 on Asus Vivo PC.

Comment: what is status of these services? `systemctl status sshd`. If you enable it manually using `systemctl enable sshd`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
systemctl is-enabled sshd.service
```

If its not enabled, try :

```
systemctl enable sshd.service
```